# call method in elixir bytecode externally

Tags: java, elixir

```
defmodule Math do
  def sum(a, b) do
    a + b
  end
end
```

I created this elixir module and created the byte code using command `elixirc file.ex`. I need to call the Math.sum() from another program using the bytecode.
Can I call this method in a java program using

```
String startErlangVM = "iex";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(startErlangVM + ";" + "Math.sum(1, 2)" );
```

But this isn't working. Is there any way to call a Elixir method not calling `iex` to start Erlang virtual machine explicitly?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I think it's better to communicate over network ports if you want to interface with another program written in another language.

Comment: I want to run a program with multi-core support. Front end is in java. But java VM doesn't support parallel programming. Only one thread will  run at a time. Elixier is better in parallel programming. So I tried to create the back end using elixir. I need help on calling the elixir methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to run a program with multi-core support. Front end is in java. But java VM doesn't support parallel programming. Only one thread will run at a time. Elixier is better in parallel programming. So I tried to create the back end using elixir. I need help on calling the elixir methods.

In this case, to use the power of concurrency, you should implement the Java front end as a TCP client. And implement the Elixir backend as a TCP server, that is handling client requests and respond with messages.